# I want to wire my outdoor solar motion light to my indoor led string light, (ie: inside an RV)

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, motion-sensor

I've seen this done however I'm not sure how to accomplish this without a little help. I would like to find a way to wire my outdoor solar motion sensor light to my indoor led light string. Ideally I was trying to figure out how to make it where on either side of my RV would be a motion light and two separate light strings inside my RV,so theoretically when activated,on whichever side the movement is on, the one set of lights would turn on as well, therefore letting me know inside as well when there is something outside. I have 1 everbrite (solar outdoor) and 1 dimirus (outdoor solar), and plenty of led light strings.

Comment: You will need to supply model and/or photos of the connections on the motion sensor and details on the led string.

Comment: What does your size or sex have to do with anything?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea might work, or *might not*, if the PIR motion sensor light can't supply enough current for the light string.

However, you can buy 12 volt PIR motion sensors for ~US$5 or more apiece, such as [some of these from Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=12%20v%2024%20v%20pir%20sensor). The sensors are designed to make connection simple, rather than trying to cut open an existing light with a PIR sensor and rewiring it.

BTW, if you want to put the sensors in *parallel*, so that both front and back sensors trigger one string of lights, *put a diode in series with each sensor* to prevent feeding current from one to another.

Also, consider the *standby* current drain of each sensor, so you don't kill the RV battery, when it's not being charged.

Comment: I can't imagine that a PIR is going to draw enough current to drain an RV battery over night or even over a week. I have multiple battery-powered PIR sensors around my house and they claim 2+ years of battery life on a CR2032(?) battery. I'm at ~1 year so far on some of them and they're still reporting > 50% battery life. TBF, that _is_ something to think about, but I can't imagine it being a _huge_ issue...

Comment: @FreeMan, agreed, mot PIR sensors have low standby power. However, the devices in the reference did *not* have detailed specs, and it might be a good idea to check... and the total drain when all are on, as well.

Comment: Good points. Not an RV expert, by far, but I think most of them have some sort of battery monitoring and standby generation. If not, they certainly should!